# insserv: There is a loop between service foo and bar if started... Breaks aptitude

Tags: init.d

Does anyone know how to resolve these init errors that happen from the Cyberpower powerpanel for linux package?

Ref:
http://www.cyberpowersystems.com/products/management-software/ppl.html

-

I tried using nut instead, but it has issues, namely Debian bug 354429 that effectively disables syslog, and thus nut is not an option.

Ref: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=354429

---

Output:

```
root@host:~# aptitude install foo

The following NEW packages will be installed:

  foo python-central{a}

The following packages are RECOMMENDED but will NOT be installed:

  whois

0 packages upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.

Need to get 0 B/144 kB of archives. After unpacking 1,016 kB will be used.

Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?]

Selecting previously deselected package python-central.

(Reading database ... 16630 files and directories currently installed.)

Unpacking python-central (from .../python-central_0.6.16+nmu1_all.deb) ...

Selecting previously deselected package foo.

Unpacking foo (from .../foo_x.x.x-x_all.deb) ...

Processing triggers for man-db ...

Setting up python-central (0.6.16+nmu1) ...

Setting up foo (x.x.x-x) ...

insserv: warning: script 'K99pwrstatd' missing LSB tags and overrides

insserv: warning: script 'pwrstatd' missing LSB tags and overrides

insserv: There is a loop at service pwrstatd if started

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Max recursions depth 99 reached

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: There is a loop between service stop-bootlogd and mountnfs if started

insserv:  loop involving service mountnfs at depth 8

insserv:  loop involving service nfs-common at depth 7

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: There is a loop between service pwrstatd and mountall if started

insserv:  loop involving service mountall at depth 4

insserv:  loop involving service checkfs at depth 3

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv:  loop involving service mountnfs-bootclean at depth 10

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv:  loop involving service networking at depth 6

insserv: There is a loop between service stop-bootlogd and udev if started

insserv:  loop involving service udev at depth 1

insserv: There is a loop between service stop-bootlogd and checkroot if started

insserv:  loop involving service checkroot at depth 2

insserv:  loop involving service keyboard-setup at depth 1

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: There is a loop at service stop-bootlogd if started

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv:  loop involving service kbd at depth 12

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: There is a loop between service pwrstatd and mountoverflowtmp if started

insserv:  loop involving service mountoverflowtmp at depth 7

insserv:  loop involving service mountall-bootclean at depth 6

insserv:  loop involving service hwclockfirst at depth 2

insserv:  loop involving service hostname at depth 3

insserv:  loop involving service mtab at depth 5

insserv: There is a loop between service stop-bootlogd and ifupdown-clean if started

insserv:  loop involving service ifupdown-clean at depth 5

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: There is a loop between service stop-bootlogd and mdadm-raid if started

insserv:  loop involving service mdadm-raid at depth 3

insserv:  loop involving service mountkernfs at depth 1

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd andconfigured to not write apport 
reports therefore on system facility     `$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!

update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header

dpkg: error processing foo (--configure):

subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1

Processing triggers for python-central ...

Errors were encountered while processing:

 foo

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

A package failed to install.  Trying to recover:

Setting up foo (x.x.x-x) ...

insserv: warning: script 'K99pwrstatd' missing LSB tags and overrides

insserv: warning: script 'pwrstatd' missing LSB tags and overrides

insserv: There is a loop at service pwrstatd if started

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Max recursions depth 99 reached

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: There is a loop between service stop-bootlogd and mountnfs if started

insserv:  loop involving service mountnfs at depth 8

insserv:  loop involving service nfs-common at depth 7

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: There is a loop between service pwrstatd and mountall if started

insserv:  loop involving service mountall at depth 4

insserv:  loop involving service checkfs at depth 3

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv:  loop involving service mountnfs-bootclean at depth 10

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv:  loop involving service networking at depth 6

insserv: There is a loop between service stop-bootlogd and udev if started

insserv:  loop involving service udev at depth 1

insserv: There is a loop between service stop-bootlogd and checkroot if started

insserv:  loop involving service checkroot at depth 2

insserv:  loop involving service keyboard-setup at depth 1

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: There is a loop at service stop-bootlogd if started

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv:  loop involving service kbd at depth 12

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: There is a loop between service pwrstatd and mountoverflowtmp if started

insserv:  loop involving service mountoverflowtmp at depth 7

insserv:  loop involving service mountall-bootclean at depth 6

insserv:  loop involving service hwclockfirst at depth 2

insserv:  loop involving service hostname at depth 3

insserv:  loop involving service mtab at depth 5

insserv: There is a loop between service stop-bootlogd and ifupdown-clean if started

insserv:  loop involving service ifupdown-clean at depth 5

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: There is a loop between service stop-bootlogd and mdadm-raid if started

insserv:  loop involving service mdadm-raid at depth 3

insserv:  loop involving service mountkernfs at depth 1

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: Starting pwrstatd depends on stop-bootlogd and therefore on system facility 
`$all' which can not be true!

insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!

update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header

dpkg: error processing foo (--configure):

 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1

Processing triggers for python-central ...

Errors were encountered while processing:

 foo



root@host:~# dpkg -r powerpanel

(Reading database ... 16715 files and directories currently installed.)

Removing powerpanel ...

Stopping  pwrstatd 1.1.4.

uninstallation accomplish!

Processing triggers for man-db ...

root@host:~# aptitude install foo

The following partially installed packages will be configured:

  foo

No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.

0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.

Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.

Setting up foo (x.x.x-x) ...

Processing triggers for python-central ...



root@host:~# dpkg -i powerpanel_1.1.4_amd64.deb

Selecting previously deselected package powerpanel.

(Reading database ... 16694 files and directories currently installed.)

Unpacking powerpanel (from powerpanel_1.1.4_amd64.deb) ...

Setting up powerpanel (1.1.4) ...

Starting pwrstatd 1.1.4.

Installation accomplish!



Processing triggers for man-db ...

root@host:~#
```

Answer (score 11):

I put the following into /etc/init.d/pwrstatd:

```
#!/bin/sh

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          pwrstatd
# Required-Start:    udev
# Required-Stop:
# Should-Start:
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:
# Short-Description: PowerPanel to monitor CyberPower UPS
### END INIT INFO
```

It seemed to make sense to make it rely on udev.

To verify that this works, if you have insserv and graphviz installed (this question is for Debian after all), run:

```
/usr/share/insserv/check-initd-order -g > boot.dot
dotty boot.dot
```

Comment: Here's where I pulled the init script dependency graph hints from: [http://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts/DependencyBasedBoot]

Comment: I ended up doing this for my problem that I was encountering but it was on my `/etc/init.d/rc.local` file. In `chroot`, I changed the `$all` to `udev` and ran `apt-get -f install` to fix the package manager. Then I changed it back and ran `apt-get upgrade` normally and it worked great!

Comment: Helped me a lot, thank you dols. But "dotty" are not available at Debian-Jessy, so don't know how to check boot.dot else.
But anyway, this fix my issue. Thank you.

Comment: dotty *is* available in Debian Jessie, in the graphviz package.